# how to use codeigniter where in on comma seperated row values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my project and implementing search. I want to filter users from users table with cars they own. Structure of this table is shown below

```
+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------+
| #id | username |        cars         | other_details |
+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------+
|   1 | MAC      | Jaguar,Porche       | --            |
|   2 | DEV      | Porche,Ferrari,Ford | --            |
|   3 | MONICA   | Ford,Audi           | --            |
+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------+
```

On front end, I am selecting cars from checkboxes which are returning car array for find users who have these cars like ["Porche","Ferrari"]. I am not able to find solution for how to get users using codeigniter active records in model. Please help me find out how to get users/rows having cars available in array.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First step should be schema normalization. Otherwise you will end up with `FIND_IN_SET` or other suboptimal splitting solutions.

Comment: I will not be able to normalize this column because of dependencies. I can go with FIND_IN_SET but don't know how to use it with array.

Comment: There are two ways...
Either break your `POST` array and use `LIKE` with `foreach`
Or use `RLIKE` in query

Comment: I have large number of rows. So, I want to filter it on database side on model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find answer.
First I had implode array with comma(,) and then use sql query and regular expression for getting an answer like this;

```
$this->db->sql("select * from users where `cars` NOT REGEXP '$cars'");
```

This query give data according to my requirement.